# A driven quantum harmonic oscillator (DQHO)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

> I'm trying to find the dispersion relation for the DQHO with Lagrangian
>   $$ L(q,\dot q,t)=\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2-\frac{1}{2}\omega q^2+F(t)q $$
>   with $F(t)$ being non-zero for $0<t<T$.
>   The oscillator was in its ground state for all time $t < 0$ until the force
>   starts acting on it.

So I'm trying to find the dispersion relation for the ground state at times $t>T$, and I want to find also how the $ ΔΕ*T $  behave us a function of time.

I have compute until now the $$q(t)=q_0(t)+\frac{i}{2\omega}[\tilde{F}(\omega)e^{-i\omega t}-c.c] $$

$$|v\rangle=\frac{{α}\dagger^2}{v!}|v=0\rangle $$ where $|v\rangle$ its the new states , $|n\rangle$ the QHO states with relation : $$ |n=0\rangle=e^{-f^2/2}\sum \frac{f^ν}{\sqrt{ν!}}|ν=0\rangle $$

where $$ f= \frac{|\tilde{F}(\omega)|^2}{2\hbar \omega} $$

ANd after that i found that the $$ \langle n=0|H(t>T)|n=0\rangle=\frac{1}{2}+f^2 $$

and $$ \langle n=0|H^2|n=0\rangle=\frac14+f^2 $$

So the  dispersion relation $$ (ΔΕ)=f^2 $$ and $$ (ΔΕ)*T=f^2*T$$

But I think that something is wrong  because I cannot find a relation as a function of $t$ by this dispersion relation, and as I test it for some random $F(t)$, it doesn't give me the result I want or either some relation $(ΔΕ)(t)$. Any ideas or hints ?

Comment: Really what is off-topic about asking if the form of the dispersion relation is right and how should is be? 
You say "some effort" , I have solved all the problem and i dont ask for the solution ..
Also this is a problem that i'm dealing for fun to do some introduction to very first interaction problems... and not Homework that you always tab me!!

Comment: This is a useful material, helped me with DQHO: http://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/optics/Courses/QuantumMechanicsForOptics/Oscillator.pdf